# Finitely generated projective modules over a simple algebraic ring extension of a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, projective-module

The well-known theorem of Quillen-Suslin says that a finitely generated projective module over $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is free,
See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19584/what-is-the-insight-of-quillens-proof-that-all-projective-modules-over-a-polyno

What can be said about a finitely generated projective module over a simple algebraic ring extension of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$? Namely, let $w$ be algebraic over $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. What can be said about a finitely generated projective module over $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n][w]$?

I do not know if this question is difficult or trivial (=for example, if there is a known result which says what is the connection between finitely generated projective modules over a ring $R$ and finitely generated projective modules over a simple algebraic ring extension of $R$).

Comment: In general there is little you can say. For example, they could be regular, but not a UFD, giving non-trivial projective modules of rank one.

Comment: Yes. For example, consider $k[x]\subset k[x,y]$ where $y^2=x^3+1$. Then $k[x,y]$ is regular, but not a UFD.

Comment: But I wish to consider $k[x,y] \subseteq k[x,y][w]$

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your example; $k[x,y]$ IS a UFD

Comment: Add a variable! For example $k[x,y]\subset k{x,y][w]$ with $w^2=x^3+1$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Please why $k[x,y][w]$, $w^2=x^3+1$, is regular? And more important: Do you know any criterion which will make $k[x,y][w]$ regular? (actually it is enough for me to know when such an extension is normal, not necessarily regular). I have once asked that question and have not yet got any answer (I will try to find it soon).

Comment: Or maybe my question is still too general? (I know there is a normality criterion by Serre, but I am not sure if it is helpful in my "general" case).

Comment: Please look up Jacobian Criterion for regularity.

Comment: I have tried to use that criterion (you mean, the one that appears, for example, in Eisenbud's book theorem 16.19?) for $k[x,y][w]=k[x,y,z]/(h)$ with $h$ the minimal polynomial of $w$ over $k[x,y]$, but did not understand what that criterion really says in my case (I do not know how exactly $h$ looks like). Any hints are welcomed. Thanks anyway.

Comment: $z$ corresponds to $w$ and thus $h(x,y,z)=z^2-w^3-1$.

Comment: Oh, you suggested the Jacobian criterion to show that your specific example is regular; thanks. I thought that you meant that the Jacobian criterion will solve my general question, where $h$ is not exactly known (I guess that without any further details, it is impossible to decide if $k[x,y][w]$ is regular or not. In a previous question I have asked if one can suggest a condition which guarantees the regularity of $k[x,y][w]$).

Comment: You probably meant $h(x,y,z)=z^2-x^3-1$.

Comment: @Mohan I think your example with $h(x,y,z)=z^2-x^3-1$ is NOT regular, since all partial derivatives are zero at $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: $h(0,0,0)\neq 0$.

Comment: @Mohan My mistake...you are right, there is no need to check the derivatives in that case. Please, if you wish to write your first comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general there is little you can say. For example, they could be regular, but not a UFD, giving non-trivial projective modules of rank one.